# Ordered triplets of numbers

Tags: math, combinatorics

> Hello everyone, I am solving a problem to count the no. of ordered triples of different numbers (X1,X2,X3) where X could be any from 1 to Ni for i=1,2,3

For 2 4 2

o/p is 4

For 25 12 2012

o/p is 578880

> What is the meaning of ordered triples here in the above problem??
>
> Thanx very much in advance

Comment: Codechef has this policy against any sort of cheating, you know.

Comment: @Chocolava I know it very well and I have not cheated. Thats why you can see i have asked for clarifying the question only :)

Comment: https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/5146/threedif-editorial

Answer (score 3):

> What is the meaning of ordered triples here?

A *triple* consists of three numbers. Thus, the following are triples:

```
 1 2 3
10 2 5
 1 1 7
```

In an *ordered* triple, the order matters. Thus, the following are considered different even though they consist of the same set of numbers

```
1 2 5
1 5 2
2 1 5
...
```

Comment: What does this mean in relation to the above context?

Answer (score 2):

And for your  example 2 4 2, the ordered triples of different numbers would be:

As X1 varies 1 to 2 , X2 varies 1 to 4 and X3 varies 1 to 2

```
X1 X2 X3
1, 3, 2
1, 4, 2
2, 3, 1
2, 4, 1
```

Comment: how do you determine those ordered triples though. For example why wouldnt 1,2,1 be an ordered triple since x2 varies from 1-4

Comment: @WillJamieson: the OP mentions "ordered triples of **different** numbers".

Answer (score 2):

if you want to calculate the total number of ordered triples

```
Arrays.sort(n);
int answer= n[0]*(n[1]-1)*(n[2]-2);
```

Comment: please tell us how u end up in that solution